# Unable to build and install binutils in Kali linux

Tags: linux, makefile, binutils, os161

I was trying to install OS 161 KALI LINUX version 2020.3 64bit. The first step was to build and install binutils.

The procedure I followed is shown in this [image].

I configured the binutils and got this output https://pastebin.com/iXjFq3Zu  but upon running i got the make command i got the following errors https://pastebin.com/DYSBdUqq .

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [Makefile:2551: as-new] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/digzsudi/Downloads/binutils-2.17+os161-2.0.1/gas'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:2596: all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/digzsudi/Downloads/binutils-2.17+os161-2.0.1/gas'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:2482: all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/digzsudi/Downloads/binutils-2.17+os161-2.0.1/gas'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:4860: all-gas] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/digzsudi/Downloads/binutils-2.17+os161-2.0.1'
make: *** [Makefile:627: all] Error 2
root@kali:/home/digzsudi/Downloads/binutils-2.17+os161-2.0.1#
```

Comment: Is your Kali OS 32 or 64 bit OS?

Comment: You did not show us the actual error.  The errors appear _before_ the text here.  This is just telling you that something failed, not what failed.

Comment: @mail2bapi it is a 64bit kali linux 2020.3

Comment: @MadScientist  I've  added a link to the pastebin  where I've pasted the code

Comment: Did anyone know the answer?